# Model registration in django in admin.py multi model (choicefield selection)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

here is my admin.py

```py
class ResumeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        fields = ['category']
        if obj:
            if obj.category == 'Summary':
                fields.extend(['summary_title', 'summary_description', 'summary_address', 'summary_phone', 'summary_email'])
            elif obj.category == 'Education':
                fields.extend(['edu_title', 'edu_course', 'edu_start_date', 'edu_end_date', 'edu_gpa'])
            elif obj.category == 'Experience':
                fields.extend(['exp_title', 'exp_date', 'exp_where', 'ext_explanation', 'exp_project_link'])
            elif obj.category == 'Projects':
                fields.extend(['project_title', 'project_description', 'project_link'])
            elif obj.category == 'Certifications':
                fields.extend(['cert_title','cert_date', 'cert_where', 'cert_explanation','cert_project_link'])
        return fields

admin.site.register(Resume, ResumeAdmin)
```

and this is my model.py

```py
class Resume(models.Model):
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Summary', 'Summary'),
        ('Education', 'Education'), 
        ('Experience', 'Experience'),
        ('Projects', 'Projects'),
        ('Certifications', 'Certifications'),
    )
    
    # view different fields according to the category
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY, default='Projects')
    
class Summary(models.Model):
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    summary_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    summary_description = models.TextField()
    summary_address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    summary_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    summary_email = models.EmailField()

# 2 Education option will have title, course, start_date, end_date, GPA
class Education(models.Model):
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    edu_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    edu_course = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    edu_start_date = models.DateField()
    edu_end_date = models.DateField()
    edu_gpa = models.FloatField()
    
# 3 experience filed will have same as education filed
class Experience(models.Model):
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    exp_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    exp_date = models.CharField(max_length=100) # it holds the start and end year of the course
    exp_where = models.CharField(max_length=200) # college or school name
    ext_explanation = models.TextField()
    exp_project_link = models.URLField()
    
# 4 projects filed will have title, description, project_link
class Projects(models.Model):
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    project_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    project_description = models.TextField()
    project_link = models.URLField()
    
class Certifications(models.Model):
    resume = models.ForeignKey(Resume, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cert_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cert_date = models.CharField(max_length=100) # it holds the start and end year of the course
    cert_where = models.CharField(max_length=200) # college or school name
    cert_explanation = models.TextField()
    cert_project_link = models.URLField()
```

i want to create smtng like this where inside a single model having reference to different classes in django but then there are many different inputs like the variations of each class  the output i want to achieve is that when a particular choice is selected then the tables of that should be displayed below

and reference like this is possible (i want the way how this can be dont too)

```
{for values in  Resume.Experience }
context here
{end for}
```

is there any way to do so ?

Comment: I think *inlines* is a way to go

Comment: i see then what about the last part of my question how should that look like ? that loop you may say .... thanks btw